# ASP.net giving list to Android how to parse with KSOAP2

Tags: asp.net, android, android-ksoap2

I have an asp.net webservice which is giving me this:

```
 <ArrayOfString>
<string>Musterbetrieb</string>
<string>Testbetrieb</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Now i want to parse it with android, its working for a single string but not for this?
How can i get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse it. You can use any parsing techniques which is provided by Android i.e. DOM Parsing, SAX parsing etc. Good [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#download) for xml parsing in android.

Comment: Im crashing here: SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope2.getResponse();
Im not getting any answer? Logcat says:
03-11 09:18:17.503: WARN/System.err(511): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject